# Create a collection associated with a user in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

> Hello Friends I have an app in which I have not been able to modify it
> so that each collection of activities is associated with the user who
> is logged in, I have made modifications but it must be that I do not
> know very well how to handle collections and that is why I need your
> help, thank you very much for your input. I send the model and
> associated files of the application

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:todo_app_firestore_example/utils.dart';

class TodoField {
  static const createdTime = 'createdTime';
}

class Todo {
  DateTime createdTime;
  String title;
  String id;
  String description;
  bool isDone;

  Todo({
    @required this.createdTime,
    @required this.title,
    this.description = '',
    this.id,
    this.isDone = false,
  });

  static Todo fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Todo(
        createdTime: Utils.toDateTime(json['createdTime']),
        title: json['title'],
        description: json['description'],
        id: json['id'],
        isDone: json['isDone'],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'createdTime': Utils.fromDateTimeToJson(createdTime),
        'title': title,
        'description': description,
        'id': id,
        'isDone': isDone,
      };
}


import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:todo_app_firestore_example/model/todo.dart';
import 'package:todo_app_firestore_example/utils.dart';

class FirebaseApi {
  static Future<String> createTodo(Todo todo) async {
    final docTodo = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('todo').doc();

    todo.id = docTodo.id;
    await docTodo.set(todo.toJson());

    return docTodo.id;
  }

  static Stream<List<Todo>> readTodos() => FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('todo')
      .orderBy(TodoField.createdTime, descending: true)
      .snapshots()
      .transform(Utils.transformer(Todo.fromJson));

  static Future updateTodo(Todo todo) async {
    final docTodo = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('todo').doc(todo.id);

    await docTodo.update(todo.toJson());
  }

  static Future deleteTodo(Todo todo) async {
    final docTodo = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('todo').doc(todo.id);

    await docTodo.delete();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can someone help me with this modification, I thank you in advance